# Syntax error on token ":", invalid AssignmentOperator in eclipse ide

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, interface, syntax-error

I am just trying to learn how to use interface and Lambda expressions. I don't think i did any thing wrong but I getting a Syntax error.

```
package Main;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        InfacePrintToConsole console = (String text) -> {};     
        console.defPrint(text:"main"); // Error here        
    }
}
```

```
package Main;

import java.io.OutputStream;

public interface InfacePrintToConsole {
    
    void print(String text);
    
    default public void defPrint(String text) {
        System.out.print(text);
    };
    
    static void println(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }   
}
```

Comment: What does `text:"main"` suppose to mean? Your `defPrint` method expects a `String`.

Comment: `text:"main"` is not valid Java. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Is it a typo ? console.defPrint("text:\"main\"")

Comment: Java does not allow you to specify argument names, _unlike_ C#.

Comment: I was following this guys tutorial he used text: followed by the string https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=231&v=GxZWMgpMuLs&feature=emb_logo

Comment: @InvalidstringError007Strings Please edit that YouTube link into your question. It's normally not a useful part of questions, but in this particular case it turns out that what happened is that you confused an IDE display feature for the actual code, and _that_ could be useful to future searchers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

text: which is grayed, isn't a real text input, but an Intellij feature  [Viewing Method Parameter Information](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/viewing-method-parameter-information.html#configure_parameter_hints_in_editor)

> have the list of parameter types for the called method or function shown automatically after a certain delay

It helps you find the parameter name you are inputting , remove it from real code

```
console.defPrint("main");
```